# C# regex replace in paths

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to use regex_replace in c#

This are my strings

```
my\old\path\Win32\my.dll
my\old\path\Win64\mydll2.dll
```

I'm trying to replace them with

```
my\new\path\Win32Release\my.dll
my\new\path\Win64Release\mydll2.dll
```

This is how I do it and doesn't work in c# but works in notepad++

```
Regex.Replace(test, @"\bmy\\old\\(.*)\\[a-z]+([0-9]{2})\\((.*)+\.[a-z]{3})\b", @"my\\new\\path\\Win\2Release\\\3")
```

Comment: Dont get me wrong im a massive lover of regex but i reckon in this case it would be much simpler to use string.replace()?

Comment: You don't to match the whole string, just the part you want to change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pattern doesn't work because you have forgotten to make it case-insensitive. You can add `(?i)` at the begining of the pattern or use `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase`

Answer (score 1):

replace:

```
\\Win(..)\\
```

with:

```
\\Win($1)Release\\
```